# display pdf within google drive

Tags: android, pdf, google-drive-api

I found simple solution if anyone ask solution use these it is not necessary to use webview.

```
 String fullPath = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1svKjgGhtS90u7n4D64ZcnzGxh9-X4kJx";
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fullPath));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: You want to add or you want to show?

Comment: I want to add a link in my application. so I want to display pdf file with my apps.

Comment: I mean my link is not start with "...doc.google...." my link is start "..drive.google..."  and it doesnt work

Comment: just send demo link

Comment: here is demo link. my google drive link is same: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16f9Z9VbJmCc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution if anyone ask solution use these it is not necessery to use webview.

```
  String fullPath = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1svKjgGhtS90u7n4D64ZcnzGxh9-X4kJx";
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fullPath));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
```